# How to verify that the CA cert is OK - capistrano github deployment ssh problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, github, capistrano

Hello helpful fellows,
when trying to deploy my rails application from a local windows 7 aptana client via capistrano, the following error occurs:

** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote  (myrepo.git) branch"
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://myaccountdetails@github.com/myrepository.git/info/refs

I can push and pull as well as ssh verify from my client to github. My server setup (gentoo) has been currupted by an unsuccessful Java package installation, some setup under etc/.ssh/ has been changed at that time as well. Already tried:

deploy.rb ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true (does not seem to work for me)

I don't know how to setup the ssh details correctly on the server, please advise for dummies... oh yes - it worked before, and no, I can't ask the guy who made the initial setup - unfortunately...

Thank you very much in advance for your kind help!
Markus

Answer (score 0):

http://help.github.com/linux-key-setup/  You will have to generate a new keypair if your .ssh direcory is removed/messed with as your private key will be gone.  Also make sure you have the certificates in /etc/ssl/certs.  There should be a lot of certificates in there.

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for your answer. I can't get it to accept it. What is the difference between my user/.ssh/ setup and the etc/apache2/ssh/server.key and corresponding setup files? I still don't understand what the error message realy relates to. For me it sounds like it's asking for a server certificate.

I have both my private and public keys generated and put them in my home/ssh dir. I added them to my github ssh public keys - but that didnt change anything.

What do you mean by "make sure you have them in /etc/ssl/certs. There are many certs in there, but I can't really find out ho

Comment: Markus, Please set environment variable GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 in your shell, and post the output in your question that you get when you try to push.  Thanks

Comment: Michael, very nice, thanks for your help... Believe it or not, the CURL installation itself was corrupted on the server... Again thanks!